# "Service is currently unavailable" while connecting to Azure Cosmos DB from the local machine

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We have a weird issue when locally debugging an Azure Function V1 with Cosmos DB Trigger. When the app starts, it waits for a couple of minutes and then throws an exception "Service is currently unavailable":

[image: image.png]

The same app works just fine when I run it from home. It also runs perfectly when deployed to Azure.

Also, a similar app implemented with Azure Functions V2 works on the problematic machine.

The machines causing the issue are in the corporate network. We use real connection strings, not emulators, with `https` in it.

It really looks like a client connectivity issue... What can it be and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following change in `host.json` file fixed the issue:

```json
{
  "documentDB": {
    "connectionMode": "Gateway",
    "protocol": "Https"
  }
}
```

Azure Functions V1 connections to Cosmos DB defaults to Direct Mode, while V2 (which needed to run in any platform as Functions V2 is multi-platform) defaults to Gateway mode. Direct Mode sometimes can have issues in Firewalled environments.

Read more:

- [Azure Cosmos DB + Functions Cookbook — Connection modes](https://medium.com/@Ealsur/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-connection-modes-ecf405a750d9)
- [host.json reference for Azure Functions 1.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1)

Comment: For those using Azure cosmos db with Asp Core change  ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway when initation connection in StartUp.cs